# get url table into a `data.frame` R-XML-RCurl

Tags: xml, r, web-scraping, rcurl

I'm trying to get the table of an url into a `data.frame`. In other examples I found the following code worked:

```
library(XML)
library(RCurl)
theurl <- "https://es.finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=BEL20.BR"
tables <- readHTMLTable(theurl)
```

As the warning says the table doesn't seem to be XML

`Warning message:
XML content does not seem to be XML: 'https://es.finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=BEL20.BR'`

Alternatively, `getURLContent(theurl, ssl.verifypeer = FALSE, useragent = "R")` works but don't know how to extract the table. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: thanks to @har07 using `table <- readHTMLTable(getURLContent(theurl, ssl.verifypeer = FALSE, useragent = "R"))$ yfncsumtab` gives the output but still have to be filtered.

Comment: Pass result of `getURLContent` as parameter of `readHTMLTable()` ?

Comment: @har07 thanks that is a good improvement. I can think of finding the index of the header using `grep` and then extract the table but is there an efficient way to extract directly the table into a dataframe?

Comment: You really shouldn't use `grep` on xml/html content.

Comment: Using `ssl.verifypeer = FALSE` is an extremely BAD idea.

Comment: @hadley thanks for pointing that out. What the alternative would be for an error such as `Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  :    SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed`

Comment: @AP13 Use `httr` which sets up RCurl to avoid the problem in the first place

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the table if you use `getURL` to get the document content.  Sometimes `readHTMLTable` has trouble getting content.  In those cases, it is recommended to try `getURL`

```
> library(XML)
> library(RCurl)
> URL <- getURL("https://es.finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=BEL20.BR")
> rt <- readHTMLTable(URL, header = TRUE)
> rt
```

You might need to adjust the `header` argument and possibly others, but the tables are there.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I was using `getURLContent`since `getURL`gives me error `Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : 
  SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details:
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed`

Comment: the error is solved by adding `ssl.verifypeer = FALSE` to the `getURL`call but get a very similar result to that using `getURLContent`.

Comment: @ Richard Scriven yes, I have upvoted your answer already since it helps. I'm still trying to figure out how to automatically get the contents of the table only, that is, the table with headers: symbol, name, etc. Note, that the table can be extracted `manually` by picking a sublist of the output of `getURL` and subsetting the appropriate rows because there are other contents that are not part of it. However, there should be a way to get the table directly instead.