# Identify web table format for scraping

Tags: r, xml, rvest

This works for me:

```
library(XML)
tables       <-  readHTMLTable("http://cdec.water.ca.gov/reportapp/javareports?name=FNF", as.data.frame = TRUE)
bottom_table <-  tables[[2]]
# process bottom_table's data, deploy to Shiny app
```

But when I use `https` instead of `http`:

```
tables       <-  readHTMLTable("https://cdec.water.ca.gov/reportapp/javareports?name=FNF", as.data.frame = TRUE)
# Warning: XML content does not seem to be XML`
```

So, I'm looking to learn how to identify the table's content type and which R library/function for scraping and preserving the table format. Thanks for any tips.

Comment: I noticed readHTMLTable() does not support `https` but this `RCurl` workaround did the trick : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25947566/get-url-table-into-a-data-frame-r-xml-rcurl

Comment: I searched on "http:// https:// [r] xml" and the second hit looked like it probably addresses your question, which I think could be phrased "why does readHTMLTable see nothing on a https:// page?"

Answer (score 0):

There are R functions to determine the class and dimensions of dataframes, which is what would be expected to be delivered by readHTMLTable with the as.data.frames parameter you offered.

```
?readHTMLTable
> class(bottom_table)
#[1] "data.frame"
> dim(bottom_table)
#[1] 40  9
```

Also:

```
?rownames
?colnames
```

Comment: For the `https` page, I'm unable to define `tables` or `bottom_table`: `tables` is returned as a List of 0.

Comment: For your second effort at accessing that data I get: `str(tables) #
 Named list()`, soI don't think you are posing the question in a manner that actually addresses the problem you are facing. Using https and that code results in an empty list rather than an object that has any table in it.